# Trying to sort a series of WordPress posts by date with null values at the end

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, date

I'm trying to sort a series of posts in WordPress by the start date, this uses a custom post type. The date is optional to enter which means if no date is entered it is treated as null.

However, the date format automatically defaults to January 1st, 1970 when it is not set, this means that no matter what, the posts with no start date are sorted at the top rather than at the bottom. Reversing the order won't work since the events with a proper date will be sorted in the wrong way.

```
// This gets all the posts and sorts them by date

$events = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'eventStarttime',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
]);

// The events are looped through in this foreach

foreach ($events as $event) {
    echo "<button aria-controls='event-{$event->ID}' class='location-navigation-item js-location-button non-mobile'>";

    $timestamp = get_field('eventStartTime', $event->ID);
    $eventUnlocked = (get_field('eventActive') === "yes") ? true : false;
    $date = strtr($timestamp, '/', '-');

    echo "<h3>".strtoupper(get_the_title($event->ID))."</h3>";

    if ($timestamp):
        echo "<h4 class='minorheading'>". date('d', strtotime($date)). '<sup>' . date('S', strtotime($date)) . '</sup>/' . strtoupper(date('M', strtotime($date)))."</h4>";
    else:
        echo "<h4 class='minorheading'>TBC</h4>";
    endif;

    echo "</button>";

    echo "<a href='".get_permalink($event->ID). "'>";
    echo "  <div class='location-navigation-item mobile'>";
    echo "    <div class='mobile-data'>";
    echo "      <h3>".strtoupper(get_the_title($event->ID))."</h3>";
    echo "      <h4 class='minorheading'>". date('d', strtotime($date)). '<sup>' . date('S', strtotime($date)) . '</sup>/' . strtoupper(date('M', strtotime($date)))."</h4>";
    echo "    </div>";
    echo "    <button aria-controls='event-{$event->ID}' class='long-button event-location-button js-event-button'></button>";
    echo "  </div>";
    echo "</a>";
}
```

Sorry for bad indentation,

As you can see on the timestamp if statement, when no date is set "TBC" is instead listed as the value, which if not added would display the date of January 1st, 1970.

I simply want the null events to be at the end rather than the beginning, I couldn't find anything online about this.

Everything else about the code works, it is ONLY the order.

Thanks for your time

Comment: If you know the code indentation is bad and you even apologize for it, why do you not improve it?

Comment: I didn't know how

Answer (score 0):

Two loops is not the faster solution anycase

```
//The events are looped through in this foreach

                        foreach($events as $event)
                        {
                            echo "<button aria-controls='event-{$event->ID}' class='location-navigation-item js-location-button non-mobile'>";

                                $timestamp = get_field('eventStartTime', $event->ID);
                                $eventUnlocked = (get_field('eventActive') === "yes") ? true : false;
                                $date = strtr($timestamp, '/', '-');

                                if ($timestamp):
                                    echo "<h3>".strtoupper(get_the_title($event->ID))."</h3>";
                                    echo "<h4 class='minorheading'>". date('d', strtotime($date)). '<sup>' . date('S', strtotime($date)) . '</sup>/' . strtoupper(date('M', strtotime($date)))."</h4>";


                                    echo "</button>";

                                    echo "<a href='".get_permalink($event->ID). "'>";
                                    echo "<div class='location-navigation-item mobile'>";
                                    echo "<div class='mobile-data'>";
                                        echo "<h3>".strtoupper(get_the_title($event->ID))."</h3>";
                                        echo "<h4 class='minorheading'>". date('d', strtotime($date)). '<sup>' . date('S', strtotime($date)) . '</sup>/' . strtoupper(date('M', strtotime($date)))."</h4>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    echo "<button aria-controls='event-{$event->ID}' class='long-button event-location-button js-event-button'></button>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                   echo "</a>";
                                endif;
                        }
reset ($events);
                        foreach($events as $event1)
                        {
                            echo "<button aria-controls='event1-{$event1->ID}' class='location-navigation-item js-location-button non-mobile'>";

                                $timestamp = get_field('eventStartTime', $event1->ID);
                                $eventUnlocked = (get_field('eventActive') === "yes") ? true : false;
                                $date = strtr($timestamp, '/', '-');

                                if (!$timestamp):
                                      echo "<h3>".strtoupper(get_the_title($event->ID))."</h3>";
                                      echo "<h4 class='minorheading'>TBC</h4>";


                                      echo "</button>";

                                      echo "<a href='".get_permalink($event1->ID). "'>";
                                      echo "<div class='location-navigation-item mobile'>";
                                      echo "<div class='mobile-data'>";
                                        echo "<h3>".strtoupper(get_the_title($event1->ID))."</h3>";
                                        echo "<h4 class='minorheading'>". date('d', strtotime($date)). '<sup>' . date('S', strtotime($date)) . '</sup>/' . strtoupper(date('M', strtotime($date)))."</h4>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    echo "<button aria-controls='event-{$event1->ID}' class='long-button event-location-button js-event-button'></button>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo "</a>";
                                endif;
                        }
```

Comment: This is only a small section of the whole script, so data variables from the first loop are used all other the script which I have shown here. The solution you showed doesn't really work, surely their is an easier way that does not require repeating all the code, thanks for your help regardless.